# How do I make a simple Multiply app in Xcode beta 6

Tags: xcode, swift, integer

Here are the direct directions from the class assignment I got. "Write an app that multiplies two numbers entered by the user. When a button is pressed, display the product of the two
numbers"

This is what I have so far:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var answer: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var textfield2: UITextField!
    @IBAction func calculatebutton(sender: AnyObject) {
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
}

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }


}
```

I'm having trouble as to what the next step would be...

Comment: This question is off-topic because it shows no attempt to solve the problem before coming here for help.

Comment: 1. Create an app. 2. Prompt for numbers. 3. Make a button. 4. Make said button show the product.

Answer (score 2):

The first step is to understand how an iOS app works.

If you are feeling extremely lost, I recommend following a tutorial, like this one : http://rshankar.com/simple-stopwatch-app-in-swift/ from start to finish.

Once you understand the basics, it will be so much more clear how to proceed with your assignment.

You'll need to:

1. **Link up** your outlets with the storyboard.
2. **Write** a function to do the math required by your assignment.
3. **Get** the parameters for your function from the textFields (eg. `var temp = textField.text`)
4. **Trigger** this function on the button press with the parameters from your `textField`s.
5. You'll want to **do** some error checking to make sure the user gives you a valid number.
6. **Display** the results.

Learning how to program is a lot of learning to google properly.

Once you **know what you need** to do from a few tutorials, you can search for help for each individual step.

(Eg. "*How to **create** a button in Swift*", "***Multiplication*** in Swift")

Comment: Good job, Sophie. Cute story on Medium.

Comment: Thanks @user3666197. Just keep swifting :)

Comment: Welcome to the MATRIX